# GLOBIGNORE='**/dont_doc/**' does not work!

Tags: bash, wildcards, globstar

I wanted to create a glob expression to ignore any file inside a `dont_doc` directory, but when I tried using using `GLOBIGNORE` to do it, it did not work:

```
$ GLOBIGNORE='**/dont_doc/**'
$ echo dont_doc/**
dont_doc/customBlockHelpers.hbs.js dont_doc/RoClasses.js dont_doc/RoEnums.js dont_doc/RoModules.js dont_doc/RoTypes.js
```

this is what I want to happen:

```
dont_doc/doc.js #Fail
dont_doc/lol/doc.js #Fail
lol/dont_doc/doc.js #Fail
lol/dont_doc/lol/doc.js #Fail
lol.js #Succsed
index.html #Fail
oof/lol.js #Succsed
```

how do I fix this?

**Edit:** I also want to ignore the `node_modules` folder

Comment: where is the `this is what happened`?

Comment: Also, why should 'index.html' fail in this scenario?

Comment: just because the glob would be this: `**/*.js *.js`

Comment: The main issue is that any pathname matching your pattern, `dont_doc/**`, does not match `**/dont_doc/**`.  This is due to the `/` in front of `dont_doc` in your `GLOBIGNORE` value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

```
GLOBIGNORE='dont_doc:*/dont_doc:dont_doc/*:*/dont_doc/*'
```

Note that it doesn't stop `bash` from looking into those directories, it just removes the entries matching those patterns from the glob expansion. So here we have 4 patterns separated with `:`, one to exclude `dont_doc` alone, one to exclude ones ending in `/dont_doc`, one to exclude ones starting with `dont_doc/`, and the last one to exclude ones containing `/dont_doc/`.

It's similar to what the `~` operator does in `zsh -o extendedglob` (like in `print -rC1 -- **/*~(|*/)dont_glob(/*|)`)

In ksh93, you just need `FIGNORE=dont_doc` for `dont_doc` directory entries to be ignored. Like `zsh -o extendedglob`'s `(^dont_glob/)#^dont_glob`, though beware that in `ksh93`, setting `FIGNORE` also disables the hiding of filenames starting with `.`.

Note that `**` only makes sense if you enable the `globstar` option to enable zsh-style recursive globbing.

If you turn the `extglob` option on in `bash` (`shopt -s extglob`), a subset of ksh's extended glob operators become available, and you can shorten the pattern to:

```
GLOBIGNORE='?(*/)dont_glob?(/*)'
```

Or to exclude more than one directory:

```
GLOBIGNORE='?(*/)@(dont_glob|node_modules)?(/*)'
```

Comment: what does the `:` do ??? and does it work with nested directory?

Comment: I don't understand why this works, can you please explain it to me, I literally just learned about globing, especially `GLOBIGNORE`

Comment: @Errorbot1122THESECOND see edit. See also `info bash GLOBIGNORE`  for details. Note that in GNU parlance (bash being the GNU shell) *filename* means what POSIX calls *pathname*, it's not limited to directory entry names.

Comment: this question is answered, but it does not work because the package I dose not check "GLOBIGNORE" so it won't work. Is there a way to use `!(...)` for my circumstance?